# Button won't trigger method

Tags: c#, asp.net

Title really says it all. I press the button and nothing happens trying to figure out why.

Default.aspx Markup (In form scope)

```
 <div class="form-group">
     <div style="text-align:center">
        <asp:Button input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" align="center"  runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit"/>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Default.aspx Code

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();

        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "myalert", "alert('Connected to ASPX file');", true); 
        //...rest of code
    }
```

**Added** Form

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <%-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags --%>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <%--- Dependencies ---%>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Content/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css"/>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <link href="./Content/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="./Content/starter-template.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="./Scripts/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

     <title>CCPOF</title>
</head>

  <body>
    <form class="form-horizontal" id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div style="text-align:center">
                <asp:Button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" align="center" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit"/> 
                <!--<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-lg" />
                    <asp:Button input type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" align="center"  runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit"/> -->
            </div>
        </div>

        <br>

    </div>
    </form>

    <!-- Bootstrap core  JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

    <script src="./Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="../../assets/js/vendor/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <script src="./Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./Scripts/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
    <embed id="embed_npfido" type="application/npfido" height="0"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @techspider copied a old version its there tho...

Comment: what are `input` attribute and `align` attributes on `Button`? You don't have `ID`!! Are you sure you know what you are trying to write?

Comment: example: `<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-lg" />`

Comment: @techspider I tried your code it just refreshes the page.. Which makes me assume since an alert didn't show up it unfortunately didn't fix it.

Comment: put a breakpoint inside your `btnSubmit_Click` and see if it reaches on click

Comment: also change to this `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` instead of `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`

Comment: Tested your code, it works just fine as it is.

Comment: Take the word input out... should be <asp:Button class="btn btn-default btn-lg" align="center"  runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit"/>

Comment: nope, nope and nope :|.. So it's probably something else I'm not showing you. Everything just makes the page refresh but nothing happens.

Comment: I'm curious what would happen if you tried an onClientClick event and put an alert inside of that function...  Maybe help narrow the scope of the issue?

Comment: @techspider debugged and setup breakpoint.. and went to it

Comment: so, what is your issue? Is `click` event getting fired? are you inside button click? Do you mean click working but not getting alert message?

Comment: @techspider I got a breakpoint hit on the last statement in the method.. But  no dialog showed up and nothing was added to db which is the point of the method >_>

Comment: the fact that it is hitting inside your method indicates your button click is firing, which is contradicting to your original question? You may have logic problems inside your button click? Did you try keeping entire code in that click inside `try/catch` block to see, if you have any other issues?

Comment: alos try this code... `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myalert", "<script>alert('Connected to ASPX file');</script>");`

Comment: @techspider wrapped everything in a try/catch and put a breakpoints in catch... but method ran through it without hitting any breakpoints.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120157/discussion-between-techspider-and-javant).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this question, I'm writing an answer from my communication with OP (please refer to comments)

A couple of changes worked for OP to get post back functional

Changing button HTML to

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" CssClass="btn btn-default btn-lg" />
```

Changing alert script to

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myalert", "<script>alert('Connected to ASPX file');</script>");
```

EDIT:

I believe OP didn't get the alert because he missed `<script>` tag